# Set maximum value (upper bound) in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I'm trying to set a maximum value of a pandas DataFrame column.  For example:

```
my_dict = {'a':[10,12,15,17,19,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

df['a'].set_max(15)
```

would yield:

```
    a
0   10
1   12
2   15
3   15
4   15
5   15
```

But it doesn't.

There are a million solutions to *find* the maximum value, but nothing to *set* the maximum value... at least that I can find.

I could iterate through the list, but I suspect there is a faster way to do it with pandas.  My lists will be significantly longer and thus I would expect iteration to take relatively longer amount of time.  Also, I'd like whatever solution to be able to handle `NaN`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I suppose you can do:

```
maxVal = 15
df['a'].where(df['a'] <= maxVal, maxVal)      # where replace values with other when the 
                                              # condition is not satisfied

#0    10
#1    12
#2    15
#3    15
#4    15
#5    15
#Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
df['a'][df['a'] >= maxVal] = maxVal
```

Comment: That's it.  Knew there was something simple I was missing.  Thanks Psidom.

Comment: Note: the two are not equivalent. The first replace also the NaN, the second just the value above the threshold (but keeping NaN).

Comment: I'd also note that it's probably better practice to use the format `df.loc[df['a'] >= maxVal, 'a'] = maxVal` but I don't have any concrete reason why it's preferred, nor have I compared timing.

Comment: If you don't use `df.loc[df['a'] >= maxVal, 'a'] = maxVal`, and instead use `df['a'][df['a'] >= maxVal] = maxVal` you are basically setting value on a copy of the dataframe, not the dataframe itself.

Answer (score 63):

You can use [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html).

Apply to all columns of the data frame:

```
df.clip(upper=15)
```

Otherwise apply to selected columns as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219211/778533):

```
df.clip(upper=pd.Series({'a': 15}), axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would prefer 
`df.clip(upper=pd.Series({'a': 15}), axis=1)`
 above 
`df.a.clip(upper=15)`?

Comment: @Hestaron One is column specific. The other isn't. If you only have one column, then you don't need to specify the column.

Comment: I don't think Hestaron's question is answered here. df.a.clip seems to have same effect but be much simpler.

Answer (score 11):

[**`numpy.clip`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) is a good, fast alternative.

```
df

    a
0  10
1  12
2  15
3  17
4  19
5  20

np.clip(df['a'], a_max=15, a_min=None)

0    10
1    12
2    15
3    15
4    15
5    15
Name: a, dtype: int64

# Or,
np.clip(df['a'].to_numpy(), a_max=15, a_min=None)
# array([10, 12, 15, 15, 15, 15])
```

---

From v0.21 onwards, you can also use [**`DataFrame.clip_upper`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html).

> **Note**
>   This method (along with `clip_lower`) has been deprecated from v0.24 and will be removed in a future version.

```
df.clip_upper(15)
# Or, for a specific column,
df['a'].clip_upper(15)

    a
0  10
1  12
2  15
3  15
4  15
5  15
```

In similar vein, if you only want to set the lower bound, use [`DataFrame.clip_lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html). These methods are also avaliable on `Series` objects.

Comment: [Deprecated since pandas 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html)

Comment: @feetwet Updated the answer with a deprecation warning. Thanks!