# how to clip pandas dataframe column-wise?

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
In [67]: a
Out[67]:

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

when I run

```
In [69]: a.clip(lower=[1.5,2.5,3.5],axis=1)
```

I got

```
ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray
```

Is that expected?
I was expecting to get something like:

```
Out[72]:

     0    1    2
0  1.5  2.5  3.5
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of a numpy array, you can use a Series so the labels are aligned:

```
df
Out: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df.clip(lower=pd.Series({'A': 2.5, 'B': 4.5}), axis=1)
Out: 
     A    B
0  2.5  4.5
1  2.5  5.0
2  3.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> lower : float or array_like, default None

According to [API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html), you're supposed to use same shaped array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

...

print df.shape

(2, 3)

print df.clip(lower=(df.clip(lower=(np.array([[n+1.5 for n in range(df.shape[1])] for _ in range(df.shape[0])])), axis=1))

     0    1    2
0  1.5  2.5  3.5
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Comment: the dimension of my df is big -- is there some trick to avoid creating another df/np.array with such dimension?

Comment: @bill OK then I suggest you to try list comprehension. Updated my code a little. But nothing comes to my mind(for now) regarding to avoid another np.array.