# Calculating a running performance score for time-series setpoint following

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time, statistics

Say I have a pandas dataframe containing time series data of a Setpoint (SP) and the actual output, as well as two calculated columns containing the setpoint delta (change from the previous timestep) and the error (Setpoint - Output).

```
     Setpoint    Output    SP Delta    Error
t0      10         10         0          0
t1      10         10         0          0
t2      20         10        10         10
t3      20         17         0          3
t4      20         19         0          1
t5      20         20         0          0
t6      25         20         5          5
t7      25         24         0          1
t8      10         25        -15        15
t9      10         14         0          4
t10     10         11         0          1
```

I'd like to calculate a running performance score (for each interval) based on a few criteria:

1. The score is bound 0 (bad) to 1 (perfect).
2. The score is not evaluated during the intervals where a setpoint change occurs (not reasonable to assume an instantaneous output response when a setpoint change occurs).
3. The score should be affected by:

   3a. The magnitude of the error

   3b. The time it takes to reach the new setpoint

Effectively, after a setpoint change, the performance score should dip to <1 and then increase back to 1 as the setpoint is achieved. The "size" and "shape" of the dip should depend on both the magnitude of error and the length of time error is non-zero. The output should look something like this (filled with arbitrary score numbers):

```
     Setpoint    Output    SP Delta    Error    Score
t0      10         10         0          0       1.0
t1      10         10         0          0       1.0
t2      20         10        10         10       NaN
t3      20         17         0          3       0.7
t4      20         19         0          1       0.9
t5      20         20         0          0       1.0
t6      25         20         5          5       NaN
t7      25         24         0          1       0.9
t8      10         25        -15        15       NaN
t9      10         14         0          4       0.7
t10     10         11         0          1       0.9
```

What I am currently doing is to calculate a single score for each event (as opposed to a continuously changing score which I'd prefer). The code will iterate through the time-series, and whenever a setpoint change occurs, a nested iteration will occur to collect all of the error values for that event and generate an error percent (event error / total possible error), which is then converted to a (0-1 bounded) score:

```
    error_lim = 0.1
    error_max = 25
    time_range = df.index.tolist()
    
    for i_iter, t_iter in enumerate(time_range):
        delta = df.at[t_iter, 'SP Delta']
        error = df.at[t_iter, 'Error']

        if error < error_lim:
            score_norm = 1
        elif delta != 0:
            error_list = []

            for ii_iter, tt_iter in enumerate(time_range[i_iter:]):
                delta_next = df.at[time_range[i_iter+1], 'SP Delta']
                error_ii = df.at[tt_iter, 'Error']

                if error_ii > error_lim and delta_next == 0:
                    error_list.append(error_ii)
                else:
                    break

            if len(error_list) == 0:
                error_perc = 0
            else:
                error_perc = sum(error_list) / (error_max * len(error_list))

            score_norm  = 1 - round(min(1, max(error_perc, 0)), 3)

        df.at[t_iter, 'Score'] = score_norm
```

Comment: Recommendations for tags: [performance] in StackOverflow is used to make code more efficient. This is not what you ask, so you may want to remove it. [statistics] and [time] are little informative. I would recommend [feedback-loop] instead.

Comment: Answered: whether satisfied or not, please do not hesitate to share a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Here is one proposal, although I believe this question should be answered from an engineering point of view first, to know *exactly* what you need to calculate, *then* work on the implementation.

It is vectorized, no nested loop, and for what it's worth, follows your desired `'Score'` quite closely.

```
# Assume maximum error is delta between current and previous Setpoint
df['MaxErr'] = df['SP Delta'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill().fillna(1)
# Where Setpoint is stable, calculate a score, normalized by this maximum error
df['Score_Abs'] = np.where(df['SP Delta'] == 0,
                           1 - abs(df['Error']/df['MaxErr']),
                           np.nan)
```

Output: (rounded to 2 decimals)

```
    Setpoint  Output  SP Delta  Error  Score_OP  MaxErr  Score_Abs
0         10      10         0      0       1.0     1.0       1.00
1         10      10         0      0       1.0     1.0       1.00
2         20      10        10     10       NaN    10.0        NaN
3         20      17         0      3       0.7    10.0       0.70
4         20      19         0      1       0.9    10.0       0.90
5         20      20         0      0       1.0    10.0       1.00
6         25      20         5      5       NaN     5.0        NaN
7         25      24         0      1       0.9     5.0       0.80
8         10      25       -15     15       NaN   -15.0        NaN
9         10      14         0      4       0.7   -15.0       0.73
10        10      11         0      1       0.9   -15.0       0.93
```

Where

- `'Score_OP'` is your provided indicative score.
- `'Score_Abs'` is the present proposal of vectorized calculation.

I was initially going for the more natural `1 - (df['Error']/df['MaxErr'])**2` instead of the absolute value. It is a possibility. The absolute value came closer to your desired output.

Rationale for the `'MaxErr'` estimate: This proposal does not allow itself to look forward in time, which you seem to be okay with but is unsettling from an engineering point of view. It only looks backwards for information on the possible error range. The *>0* constraint might not be respected if `'Setpoint'` changes by a small amount before `'Output'` has reached it (because there is no way to predict how "bad" it could get; that is one issue with your required constraints). In that case use `.clip`:

```
df['Score_Abs'] = np.where(df['SP Delta'] == 0,
                           1 - abs(df['Error']/df['MaxErr']),
                           np.nan).clip(min=0)
```

---

References:

- I used this for MaxErr code [pandas replace zeros with previous non zero value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33261359/12846804)
- clip: [Set maximum value (upper bound) in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40836208/12846804)
- To go further, I would recommend looking into [Proportional and Integral gains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional%E2%80%93integral%E2%80%93derivative_controller) page.